# Php parsing extract data from text file

Tags: php

I have the following file and I want to parse it using php and then extract data for example : pakage value is Oclbook, so `$var`Oclbook should be in `$var2`

then go deep : customer should be in `$var3`
age should be in variable and >= should be in `$var 4`
18 should be in `$var 5` and etc.....

```
$file_handle = fopen("oclbook.ocl", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$parts = explode('/n', $line_of_text);
$parts[1] = isset($parts[1]) ? $parts[1] : null;
print $parts[0] . $parts[1]. "<BR>";

}

fclose($file_handle);
```

---

```
package OclBook

context Customer
inv: age >= 18

context CustomerCard
inv: validFrom.isBefore(goodThru)


context LoyaltyProgram
inv: serviceLevel->size = 2

context Customer
inv: program->size = cards->select( valid = true )->size

context LoyaltyProgram
inv: partners.deliveredServices->forAll(
          pointsEarned = 0 and pointsBurned = 0 ) 
      implies membership.loyaltyAccount->isEmpty
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: So, what's the error/non-required behavior?

Comment: I am not able to get the variables :)